# Identity Start and End of a method

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I am creating Traces for a method and want it to use with a custom attribute. I will decorate each method with `TraceMethod`.

eg:

```
[TraceMethod()]
public void SomeMethod()
{
}

public class TraceMethod : Attribute
{
 public void StartTrace(){}

 public void EndTrace(){}
}
```

So here,

How to call `StartTrace()` before the `SomeMethod` start executing and `EndTrace()` after the execution of `SomeMethod` ends? Is it possible?

Comment: This exactly what `PostSharp` can do very good. [link](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator)

Comment: Instead of using attribute you can modify body of method to call whatever.

Comment: @Sinatr, Can you explain a bit more pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is [Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), which is something that is currently not supported out-of-the-box in the .NET world. You will have to use a third-party component; [there are some out there](https://www.google.es/?#q=aop%20.net), both paid and open sourced.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a custom class that marks the scope of a function? Create an instance of the class at the start of a function and when function terminates the class gets out of scope and destructor is called.

Constructor and destructor mark beginning and end of a function.

Edit:
As commented it is not garranteed that the destructor is called immediately after the object gets out of scope. Better is to use a `using()` block:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    using (TraceMethod trace = new TraceMethod())
    {
    }
}

public class TraceMethod : IDisposable
{
    public TraceMethod() { StartTrace(); }  // Constructor
    public void Dispose() { EndTrace(); }  // Gets called when leaving the using() block

    private void StartTrace() { ... }
    private void EndTrace() { ... }
}
```

Comment: can you post some example?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify method body:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var trace = new Trace();
    try
    {
        ... rest of method
    }
    finally
    {
        trace.EndTrace();
    }
}

public class TraceMethod : Attribute
{
    public TraceMethod() => StartTrace();

    public void StartTrace() { ... }
    public void EndTrace() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Actually @SSS looks like try to avoid this way.

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz Exactly. I am already having a static class doing the same functionality and intended to change to `Attribute`